# Character stick to bottom of ground static objects. How do I fix this?

Tags: objects, physics

Hello blender stack exchange people!
So this is a simple problem, but I haven't found a solution yet. My character is sticking to the bottom of the ground cube. I'm making a platformer game (image below) and the collision cube for my character sticks to the bottom of the collision cube for the ground (invisible) when I am pushing the up button.
[image: character sticks to bottom of ground cube]
Here's what it looks like in object mode:
[image: object mode displaying collision cubes]
That's all I can say about it... Please tell me if you need more info and what it is. My character has character physics obviously. 
I need to fix this because if the player doesn't make the jump, the character should fall instead of traveling under the cube seemingly floating through the air. Thanks a lot!
~DaDudeII

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works well enough for me. Basically, I made the ground cube skinnier and added planes that extend to the death plane (the plane that restarts the scene when you fall off the edge and die).
[image]
Unfortunately, this doesn't explain why it happens, so I can't find a more reasonable solution. But maybe someone can explain that to me.